# Mavericks php.ini configuration, working with no ini file

Tags: php, osx-mavericks, ini

I recently installed  `mcrypt` into the default installation of PHP in OS X 10.9 after getting everything configured and installed, I went to turn on the so in the `php.ini`. I noticed that there wasn't a default `php.ini` so I copied the `php.ini.default`, renaming it, adding the `extension=mcrypt.so` and restarting Apache.

Upon doing this my `phpinfo()` page shows nothing, and none of my php scripts work.

I can run `php -i` from the command line and see what should be displayed in the `phpinfo()`, the `crypt` library shows up there, and there are no errors.

If I remove all `php.ini` files from `/etc` or `/private/etc`, and restart Apache, PHP starts working again.

Looking at the `phpinfo`, it shows `/etc` as the location of the `php.ini` file. Is there some default location that `php.ini` gets an ini file when one is missing?

I assume it must be something in the `php.ini` that is causing an error and keeping php from working, but using the default ini file causes the same result.

Comment: You can use the functions `ini_get()` and `ini_set()` to help debug your problem.

Comment: If php won't run then those functions won't be able to run in a script. When I can run it, with no ini file, I can run phpinfo(), which has all the variables that the ini_get would return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my own problem. I noticed that the `phpinfo` had `Scan this dir for additional .ini files`, which was `/Library/Server/Web/Config/php` I created those directories, set the correct owner and permissions, copied my `php.ini` file there, and restarted the server. I got a blank info file again, which meant something in my ini file was causing the problem. I removed everything except the directives I added in, such as `extension=mcrypt.so`, restarted the web server and the info shows up exactly as I expected it.

Comment: This worked for me on OS X 10.9.5 with PHP 5.4.30. There was no php.ini anywhere on my filesystem, but creating the directories + file /Library/Server/Web/Config/php/php.ini enabled me to specify the name of a shared object library for a PHP extension I wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps if `breakit2fixit`'s answer doesn't help. I ran the following command to find any other php.ini files on my system:

```
find / -name php\*ini
```

I found a little guy hidden away in another version of PHP that somehow found it's way onto my box.

In this case it was in `/usr/local/php5-5.5.14/lib/php.ini`

Once I changed that I ran:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

This did the trick for me. The key is finding a stray PHP install. The weird thing is that running `php --ini` told me it was loading the `/etc/php.ini` file...